# apache domain redirect not working as expected

Tags: apache, redirect

I have the following rewrite rule in apache conf.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It redirects http://example.org/?p=18 to http://www.example.org//?p=18. It adds // at the end of domain name. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `/`. You have two choices:

1. You can avoid putting it in the target:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1$1 [R=301,L]
   ```
2. Or you can avoid capturing it in the match part:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```